# Are the vord based on a specific Pokemon?

Tags: codex-alera

The genesis of the *Codex Alera* series, by Jim Butcher, was a [bet](http://www.fantasyliterature.com/author-interviews/jim-butcher/) that he couldn’t write a good story based on the two ideas of “Pokemon” and “lost Roman legion.” Now, obviously, the furies are more the Pokemon analogues, but it occurs to me that other creatures, such as the vord, might be based on Pokemon as well.

Do the vord bear a clear resemblance to any Pokemon?

Comment: The wiki lists [8 different types of Vord](http://codexalera.wikia.com/wiki/Vord), each varying in shape. So I think you can say that the Vord in general do not have a clear resemblance to a specific Pokemon, but maybe to multiple Pokemon. I could not find any quotes by the author himself about this...

Comment: I would find this a more interesting question if it cited the claim that it was based on a bet.

Comment: @Brythan - [Here](http://www.fantasyliterature.com/author-interviews/jim-butcher/). I mentioned it in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Jim Butcher has not stated anything about the relation between Vord and Pokemon.

If there is any resemblance between the Vord and Pokemon, it is only physical resemblance, as the principles of Pokemon are not resembled with the Vord.

Physical resemblance does exist to some extend, but the anime style of Pokemon makes it difficult to argue that Jim Butcher based the description of Vord on Pokemon.

This leads me to conclude that the Vord do not bear a clear resemblance to the Pokemon.

### Vords resemble multiple different species

In general, insectoids in pop culture do not deviate a lot. In [one forum](https://forums.darklordpotter.net/threads/the-codex-alera.9733/page-5#post-256224), similarities between Vord and Olthoi were noted, both regarding physical resemblance and style of attack.

> Actually, it seems to me that Codex Alera was inspired by Asheron's Call (the MMO), for they share many similarities. [...] The Vord have a startling resemblance to the Olthoi.
>   In PY0, a young Yalaini mage named Asheron Realaidain was experimenting with portal magic when he accidentally opened portals to an alien world. This planet was the homeworld of many **monstrous insectlike species**. One of the smaller species, the Olthoi, proceeded to **invade Auberean** via the portals, and legions of **black, man-sized death machines spewed across the surface of the planet, skewering all other inhabitants on their massive pincers, their magic-resistant hides rendering them largely immune to the Empyreans' defenses.** Their invasion went almost unchecked and the Olthoi all but annihilated the Empyrean civilization.

A [Reddit user claims](https://www.reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/2f3q80/respect_the_primary_vord_queen_codex_alera/) that the Vords are

> a **Tyranid/Zerg-like species** from the Codex Alera organized with the leadership being a Queen, which is more of a type of Vord than a specific position.

### Pokemon

There is an entire class called 虫タイプ (bug type), so Pokemon has its fair share of insectoids. 
One could probably make the argument that a few Pokemon look like Vords, especially the spiders (see images below)

[image: Image Credit: Codex Alera Wikis]

Image Credit: Codex Alera Wikia

[image: Spinark Pokemon]

<s>Spinark</s> evolved form, Ariados Pokemon (*thanks **@IG_42** for catching that*)

**But**

- something like the *croatch* doesn't exist in the world of Pokemon
- the Pokemon are colourful, while the Vord are monochromatic green
- **most importantly**, the Vord are nothing like Pokemon (in comparison to furies, who do remind one of the idea behind Pokemon)

Furthermore, Butcher has never stated anything about Vord-Pokemon relations.

Comment: Also that's the evolved form of Spinarak, Ariados

Comment: @IG_42 Thanks for catching that. Updated answer.

Comment: The Vord are green, no?

Comment: @Adamant Funny, I always remembered them as pitch black... I only have the German edition, and a hard copy, nothing electronically, so it takes me a while to skim through the books to find a description of the Vorg. I've been looking for that the past half an hour...

Comment: @Adamant The Vord Queen is definitely green (German description translates to *similar to Kitai, but with a more greenish taint*), but I couldn't find anything regarding the others. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer and will continue looking for sources